# Change value of variable with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, variables

Here I have a function which return me a list of places object based on google places API
So function findPlaces is:

```
function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {
   var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
            types: ["restaurant"]
   };
```

How I want to change this variable request - types on change on list menu so this is HTML:

```
<label for="select"></label>
        <select name="select" id="select">
          <option>restaurant</option>
          <option>bar</option>
          <option>museum</option>
          <option>gas_station</option>
        </select>
```

SO I need when I change value on list/menu to change also variable request - types["newValue"]

How I can do that?

I was try with this code but dont work:

```
function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {
   var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
            types: document.getElementById("select")[document.getElementById("select").selectedInd‌ex].value
   };
```

and also try with this code but again dont work:

```
$("#select").change(function(){

        var values= $('#select option').map(function(){
                        return this.value;
                    }).get();
        var index=jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), values);

        findPlaces(boxes, index);


    });
function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {
       var request = {
           bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
                types: [index]
       };
```

How I can do that?
So first I need to on change value in HTML change the variable request - types["value"] and update the function findPlaces ???

Comment: your option should have value attribute, anyway try to use: `types: [document.getElementById("select").value]`

Comment: how, please write code...

Comment: ok, work but now I need it to onChange list/menu values to call again function findPlaces...

Comment: ok, work good, thanks, write this as answer to mark I as solution

Comment: I write now: $( "#select" ).change(function() {
route();
}); but nothing happend... becouse I need to run function again on change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a singleSelect or a multiSelect? But anyway you could try this:

```
function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {
   var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
       types: [$("#select").val()]
   };
}
```

Just use the jQuery object to select the `#select` element and use it's value (the selected element) as type.

Comment: I write now to update: $( "#select" ).change(function() {
route();
}); but nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

You must take care of using DOM methods inside your objects, because you have to respect the mvc model.

I suggest that you expose the types variable as a method and in the code that you change this type you call a method passing the new type.

```
function Places(){
    var type = "";// you could set a default value

    function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {
       var request = {
           bounds: boxes[searchIndex], 
           types: [type]
       };
    }

    function changeType(value){
        type = value
    }

}
```

So you're using js OO, and could call changeType when the selection element change.

```
var _place = new Places();

$("#selectionElement").change(function(){
    _place.changeType($(this).value);
});
```

EDIT1:

I made a example at fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/R3xb7/1/

EDIT2:

The example with your tool: [http://jsbin.com/ujExolI/1/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/R3xb7/1/)

Comment: I write now $( "#select" ).change(function() {
route();
}); but nothing happend...

Comment: look at the first line, I instantiate the obj before call.

Comment: you need to fix your entire code, on chrome press F12 and you will see a lot of bugs at the console tab. I see that you set onchange event twice, by jquery as I show and in the html code